# MapKit MapView Annotations overlapping on a real device

Tags: xcode, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have the problem depicted in the image when testing my app on a real device (iPhone 3G, 3.1.3).
It is fine in the simulator (xcode 3 with ios 4.1 sdk). sorry, can't post images yet, this is my first question here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct4on.jpg

I have the following code in the implementation of the annotation:

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    coordinate = coord;
}
return self;
}
```

And this is part of the header file:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
```

And this is where I create a new one (inside a loop):

```
MyAnnotation *theAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc]  initWithLocation:theCoordinate];
theAnnotation.title = [single objectForKey:@"address"];
theAnnotation.objID = [single objectForKey:@"id"];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:theAnnotation];
[theAnnotation release];
```

Any ideas about this? I don't know what to look :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to bring the (annotation)view to the front, when tapping on it.

So, when someone taps on an annotation, you should call `[[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];`

Best,
Christian

Comment: How do I detect when someone taps on an annotation?Also, this sounds like a hack for something that works on the simulator but not on the phone, so I was trying to figure out if this is an iOS bug or my fault...

Comment: I ended up kind of using your suggestion: I had to override MKPinAnnotationView and use your code in the "touchesBegan" method. Thanks!